# Use templates in tinymce wordpress editor and save as custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, tinymce

I'm creating a plugin to customize wordpress dashboard. I want to use the tiny mce in a plugin page so I'm calling the `wp_editor()` function to have it inside the desired page. Since I want to have some templates to use to create the content and then save it in a cpt, is this possible and how I need to proceed? is there an hook or a filter I need to call to achive this?